Do some people suffer as a response to someone elses logic?
If an individual has an absecence of logic that some other person has a presence of logic.
Does the second person suffer as a direct consequence of the first person's logic.
Do logical people have an advantage over those that are not. Is it humane to exploit the disadvantage of a person without logic.
Is there logical evidence that those that have logic exploit those that don't?

What does it mean an "absence/presence of logic"? More/less "logical hability"? Measured in what way? More/less training, depending on school? In this case are you assuming that the "more logical" will rule on the unlogical? But what about Hitler and Stalin? they were not "very schooled"... Were they "logical"?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Is logic an innate characteristic to the most and one that cannot be schooled? If it were the former they have a responsibility over those that do not share that innate logic. Hitler didn't aswell as Stalin and now we have free gear starmer in control of the UK.

Considering oneself to have logic and other people to not have logic sounds a bit too egotistical for my liking. If you don't "have logic", you wouldn't be able to figure out you need food to not starve, so it's safe to say any moderately self-sufficient person "has logic".
But any given person may or may not:

Have the ability to articulate their thoughts into the language of formal logical syllogisms.
This is really more learnt than anything else, and it can help you identify flaws in one's reasoning.

Apply logic consistently.
Some people may make exceptions in their reasoning (probably typically unknowingly) to take issue with other people's reasoning when their own reasoning suffers from the same or greater problems.

Use reasoning free of fallacies (and also knowing about different fallacies).
It would be bold for someone to assert that there are definitely zero fallacies in their own reasoning. Instead, the most one can reasonably say is that they aren't aware of any fallacies, and we should also be open to the possibility that they may be fallacies.


The advantage in all of this is that your beliefs would be better justified, so they would be more likely to correspond to what's true. This would help make the outcomes of your actions match your intentions - if you think that punching a wall would give you superpowers (due to some flaw in reasoning), you may be likely to end up with the unintended outcome of an injured hand, instead of the intended outcome of gaining superpowers.

Do those that have logic exploit those that don't

That sounds like some form of anti-intellectualism. People who have flaws in their reasoning can be exploited via those flaws. This is largely independent of how many flaws those doing the exploiting have in their reasoning (beyond them being able to spot that flaw and figure out how to exploit it... but they may do that somewhat unintentionally too, or without much understanding of the relevant underlying principles of logic).
For me, the obvious conclusion to this is not that we should abolish the study of logic, but rather that we should try to help people get rid of flaws in their reasoning, and point out that they're being exploited (presuming we consider exploitation to be bad).

Is it humane to exploit the disadvantage of a person without logic

To focus on one moral framework, utilitarianism is concerned with well-being. Inflicting suffering on others (except e.g. to protect yourself or others) would be considered immoral regardless of whether you're doing so by exploiting a flaw in someone's reasoning or via any other means.


There is a strong correlation between education and wealth
And there is reasonable evidence that education correlates positively with IQ

So it's not a very far cry to your observation that people who “have logic” can beat up (in some metaphoric sense hopefully!) those who are less endowed.
Yeah... The world is not exactly made as a model of fairness.

Yeah the world is not fair, some people are lucky and some are not. I guess you would put that down to the random nature in the origin of the universe? Right?

@8Mad0Manc8 If you ask me personally I'll tell you you to pray to God (or whatever... You can fill in the blank). Funnily enough it even works for non religious/ atheists etc. See. As to the origin of the universe its so many levels away from us it's a pointless speculation

Well my response to that is simply. Amen!

@8Mad0Manc8 You may find this also illuminating in the same direction

thanks for the light of the link you advised I visit.  I have always known the light now I know you share the light. And that gives me strength. I hope my remarks give you strength

Soon after the bumper stickers came out that said "My kid is an Honor student" we started seeing stickers that said, "My kid can beat up your honor student", along with the stick figure families, and the stick figure T-Rex chasing the stick figure family...

Yes @ScottRowe. We are humans. But more than humans we are mammals — emotion-sustained. And more than mammals we're reptiles (vertebrate if you're squeamish) — fear-aggression, sex-sleep

@Rushi yes, but beyond that, we are basically a mass of single celled organisms - scum. Actually, just a bunch of molecules. No, atoms. Elementary particles. Quarks... And you know how they are... Can't trust a single one of 'em. But, the more you know about all those things, the more money you can make. Maybe. The trend seems to be falling off now.
